# Select rows from data frame based on difference in their mean

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
> df
  ID  Chr Start  End Rank
  1 chr1   213  315   15
  2 chr1   416  535   10
  3 chr1  1012 1290   12
  4 chr1  1899 1987   13
  5 chr1  2900 3199   18
  6 chr1  3100 3200   10
```

I want to remove rows based on distance between the mean (less than 500). An example will make it clearer. For example consider row1, mean is `(Start + End) / 2`e.g.`(213 + 315)/2 = 264`. Now for row 2 mean is `(416 + 535)/2 = 475.5`. Now the difference betwen means of these rows is less than 500 `(475.5 - 264)` So I want to keep the row with highest rank and in this case row1 will be retained while 2 will be deleted. Same will happen between row 5 and 6 and row 5 will be retained. So the final output will be:

```
> df
ID  Chr    Start    End    Rank
1   chr1    213     315     15
3   chr1    1012    1290    12
4   chr1    1899    1987    13
5   chr1    2900    3199    18
```

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:6, Chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "chr1", class = "factor"), Start = c(213L, 416L, 
1012L, 1899L, 2900L, 3100L), End = c(315L, 535L, 1290L, 1987L, 
3199L, 3200L), Rank = c(15L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 10L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Chr", "Start", "End", "Rank"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Do the rows come in pairs of 2? It seem like that from you example, but it's not clear in the question

Comment: @Latrunculia I have removed the auto-generated rownames. I think that was causing confusion here. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. You seem to always compare two rows say row 1&2, row 3&4 etc... Or do you want to repeat the procedure until no two rows have a mean diff < 500?

Comment: @Latrunculia It could be the case that 3 or 4 consecutive rows have differences in there mean less than 500 so in that case based on the Rank of those rows only 1 row will be retained which will be having the maximum Rank.

Answer (score 1):

We can check the difference of the means and test if each passes the condition:

```
df[c(TRUE, diff(rowMeans(df[,3:4])) > 500),]
#   ID  Chr Start  End Rank
# 1  1 chr1   213  315   15
# 3  3 chr1  1012 1290   12
# 4  4 chr1  1899 1987   13
# 5  5 chr1  2900 3199   18
```

**Edit**

To apply the condition by pairs, we can wrap the same logic in `tapply` and group the data frame into pairs of rows. When the difference of means is greater than 500, we keep both rows, when it isn't we remove the lower ranked row:

```
library(dplyr)
df$means <- rowMeans(df[,3:4])
df %>% group_by(grps=gl(nrow(df)/2,2)) %>%
  filter(if(diff(means) > 500) TRUE else Rank == max(Rank)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-grps, -means)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
# 
#      ID    Chr Start   End  Rank
#   (int) (fctr) (int) (int) (int)
# 1     1   chr1   213   315    15
# 2     3   chr1  1012  1290    12
# 3     4   chr1  1899  1987    13
# 4     5   chr1  2900  3199    18
```

Comment: Thanks. it did the job. Sorry for my naivety, I am unable to understand the logic here. The diff take the difference between 2 consecutive rows or what, it is not clear from the definition of this function..

Comment: yes, it does. So `diff(c(1,2,3,4))` will give `[1] 1 1 1`. So this code removes always the "second" row in a pair of two consecutive rows and does't check which of them has the higher rank. But if thats not important this solution is perfect

Comment: This is not the case that I always remove "second" row, it is also possible that Rank of "second" row is higher than the first. I should also keep the "high Rank" in mind while selecting the row to keep.

Comment: I changed the df and it does keep the "first" row while ignoring the Rank of the rows. I want to keep the row which has the highest rank. Can you suggest what should be done in this case?

Comment: I am away from my desk. I will look more when I can

Comment: @pierre-laforune It is not necessary to apply 'condition by pairs'. It is also possible that 4 or 5 consecutive rows have difference in their means < 500, and in that case among those 5 rows I have to keep the one which has maximum Rank.

Comment: @pierre-lafortune Hello, I am stuck with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501840/dataframe-processing) Can you please help me with it?